# Where to go after Dummit and Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, education, book-recommendation

I am taking general abstract algebra soon and am covering most of Dummit and Foote’s book up to Galois Theory. If one wanted to continue their study of abstract algebra after this, would they read Serge Lang’s Algebra or Jacobson’s Basic Algebra I & II? How do they differ and what are pros and cons of each w.r.t. rigor, depth, and relevance?

I only mention these two books because they are on my shelf. Thanks!

Comment: Why not continue on and read the later chapters of Dummit and Foote? They give introductions to algebraic geometry, commutative algebra, homological algebra, and representation theory and character theory.

Comment: I think you should check out existing recommendations for abstract algebra books and explore on your own.  'What you should do' is best decided by you, and the best we could do is list a bunch of books.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want to do.

There is a lot of overlap in the topics covered in Lang, Jacobson, and Dummit & Foote. These are all graduate-level books, and so after working through one of these books you are presumably well-prepared to read actual research papers in algebra, or to go on to some more specialized area of algebra like representation theory, some advanced permutation group stuff, classical groups, etc.

In other words, it is likely that working through one of these books will not do a lot to advance your study of abstract algebra. They are better used as a reference to help you study advanced topics you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It depends more on the area you want to pursue than on a specific book.
One can go into detail in group theory, ring theory or Galois theory, e.g., for infinite Galois theory with profinite groups, or study algebraic number theory, algebraic geometry, commutative algebra, coding theory, cryptography, Lie algebras, representation theory, etc. All of these areas are based on abstract algebra and for each direction there are many  standard books available. Like for learning a new language, for the "dictionary part", to learn and to understand the meaning of new definitions, almost every dictionary will do - in particular the ones by Serge Lang or Nathan Jacobson.